# EKReminder with EKRecurrenceRule not saving iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, eventkit

I have a problem with saving EKReminder when I set a EKRecurrenceRule for it. When I'm saving reminder without recurrence rule, reminder is saved. Can anyone help me? I tried everything, but it still not working...

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL saved = [ self.eventStore saveReminder:self.myReminder commit: YES error: &error];
```

*saved* object returns NO instead of YES.

Comment: Can you show error message here?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no any error...

Comment: If you debug NSError *error will show the error message

Comment: Sorry, however there is a following error:
Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=18 "A repeating reminder must have a due date." UserInfo=0x1569d1b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=A repeating reminder must have a due date.}

Comment: Ok, Can you show the code where you are setting EKRecurrenceRule

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, and my code is:
`EKRecurrenceEnd *endRec=[EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:newDate];  
 EKRecurrenceRule *recur=[[EKRecurrenceRule alloc]initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily interval:   1 end:endRec];
unsigned unitFlags=NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit|NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit;  
NSDateComponents *dailyComponents=[gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:aDate];  
[self.myReminder setDueDateComponents:dailyComponents];  
[self.myReminder addRecurrenceRule:recur];`

Comment: Ok, glad you worked it out